# Progress bar disappears when i change activity in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I write code which download my video file by using async task with progress bar and it work fine..but if i change my activity or put my application in background and when i come back to my activity ( or app) than progressbar is disappears but download is still going on in background but i don't get progress bar...

I put my progress bar display code in Preexecute method of async task and dissmiss method in postexecute of asynctask..

I search on google for storing state but in my case it won't work..

here is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

     partialWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Loneworker - PARTIAL WAKE LOCK");


    setContentView(R.layout.restore);


    final Button restore =(Button)findViewById(R.id.restore);
    restore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(listOfStrings); // pass the arraylist which contains the product id return by google 

        }
    });

           }
         class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, String, ArrayList<String>> {

ArrayList<String> fileExist = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog();// this call to progress bar method display
  }

  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... passing) {
     Log.d("download file :", "In download file method");
      }



   protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage
    //Log.e("Downlaod file", "progress update");
    pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
    // dismiss the dialog after all file is downloaded
    if(fileExist.size()>0)
    {
        // if file exist array contain items than some videos are already avaliable in device so we display toast message to user 
        for(int i=0;i<fileExist.size();i++)
        { 
            // we used databasehelper object and called getvideoName method to fetch video name

        }
    }

     dissmissDialog(); // after displying message close the progress bar   
       }    

            protected Dialog showDialog() {

pDialog = new ProgressDialog(con);
 pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
 pDialog.setMessage("Téléchargement en cours Veuillez patienter s'il vous plait...."+(i+1)+"/"+Number_of_file);
 pDialog.setMax(100);
  pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
  pDialog.setCancelable(false);
  pDialog.show();
  return pDialog;


       }

     protected void dissmissDialog() {

      pDialog.dismiss();
       }
```

Any help is appreciated thank you

Answer (score 2):

Set `setOnCancelListener` property of `ProgressDialog` in to `false`

```
mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

otherwise progressDialog's view is to be dismisses when the Activity goes to Background(becase they call `onStop()`)